# َAndroid: Context menu is opened with the left click of the mouse and does not dismiss

Tags: xamarin.android, contextmenu

Context menu is opened with the left click of the mouse and does not dismiss. I must choose an option from the menu. Everything all right?
I saw this link: `https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/android/android-context-menu-with-examples`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test with the same code and everything works fine .

Context menu dismiss as expected when i click on the blank area.

[image]

Could we know what is the version of Xamarin.Forms on your side ?

Comment: My emulator is Nexuse 4 with skin WVGA800. With clicking at the bottom of the page, the menu window was closed. Thank you very much.